# C# ListView inside ListView

Tags: c#, listview

I have two listviews, The first shows the `team` and the second shows the details of the first listview items. I have this code it has a couple of problems and im still trying to figure out how to add the details for both . SO all what i want to do is having 2 lisview that allow the user to key in  the Details throw `txtbox` however the second listview is considered as details to the item in the first listview and here when i try to add the details for the second listview the error will be

> "index is out of range"

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public class Staff
    {
        private string team="";
        private int age=0;[enter image description here][1]
        private int count = 2;
        public string Team { get { return team; } set { team = value; } }
        public int Age { get { return age; } set { age = value; } } 
        //


        public int Count { get { return count; } }
        public Staff()
        {
            
        }
    }

    public class Staff0
    {
        //
        private string seg = "";
        private string var = "";
        private string par = "";
        public string Seg { get { return seg; } set { seg = value; } }
        public string Par { get { return par; } set { par = value; } }
        public string Var { get { return var; } set { var = value; } }
        //
        public Staff0(string sseg, string svar,string spar)
            {
            seg = sseg;
            var = svar;
            par =spar;
            }
    }

    public class StaffCount
    {
        private int count = 0;
        private int selitem = 0;
        public int Count { get { return count; } set { count = value; } }
        public int SelItem { get { return selitem; } set { selitem = value; } }
    }
    List<Staff> _lRowStaffs = new List<Staff>();
    List<Staff0> _lRowStaffs0 = new List<Staff0>();
    List<List<Staff0>> _lColStaffs = new List<List<Staff0>>();
    Staff GetStaff;
    Staff0 GetStaff0;
    StaffCount GetStaffCount = new StaffCount();

    private int _indexcount=0;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        UpdateListView(lv_Team);
    }

    private void btn_Add_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GetStaff = new Staff();
       GetStaff.Team = txt_Name.Text;
       GetStaff.Age = int.Parse(txt_Age.Text);
        GetStaff.Department= txt_Dept.Text;


            _lRowStaffs.Add(new Staff());
           UpdateListView(lv_Team);

     
    }
    private void UpdateListView(ListView lv)
    {
        lv.Clear();
        ListViewItem lvi;
        try
        {
            if (lv == lv_Team)
            {
                lv.Columns.Add("Team", 400);
                lv.Columns.Add("Number Staffs", 120);
                             
                for (int i = 0; i < _lRowStaffs.Count; i++)
                {
                    lvi = new ListViewItem(GetStaff.Team);
                    lvi.SubItems.Add(Convert.ToString(GetStaff.Age));
                    lv.Items.Add(lvi);
                }
            }
            else if (lv == lv_Staffs)
            {
                int _iSelItem = GetStaffCount.SelItem;
                lv.Columns.Add("Segment", 150);
                lv.Columns.Add("Variable", 100);
                lv.Columns.Add("Partly", 200);
                for (int i = 0; i < _lColStaffs.Count; i++)
                {
                    lvi = new ListViewItem(_lColStaffs[_iSelItem][i].Seg);
                    lvi.SubItems.Add(_lColStaffs[_iSelItem][i].Var);
                    lvi.SubItems.Add(_lColStaffs[_iSelItem][i].Par);
                    lv.Items.Add(lvi);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
    private void lv_Team_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        GetStaffCount.SelItem = lv_Team.Items.IndexOf(lv_Team.SelectedItems[0]);
        if (lv_Team.Items.Count == 0 || GetStaffCount.SelItem > lv_Team.Items.Count) return;
    }

    private void btnadd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        GetStaff0 = new Staff0(txtseg.Text, txtvar.Text, tatpar.Text);
     
        _lColStaffs.Add(new List<Staff0>());
        UpdateListView(lv_Staffs);
    }
}
```

Comment: ListView.SelectedIndex == -1 means no selection so you can use this not to select the second listview if the first one has no selection

Comment: The main issue is how do i create two listviews, the second one considered as details for the first one.

Comment: On the selection of one item in the first list view, clear, load and select one item in the second list view.

Comment: Use SelectedIndexChanged event to do something on listview2 like in this example: https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listview.selecteditems?view=windowsdesktop-6.0#exemples

Answer (score 0):

Here is a similar example:
[image]

You can find the code source in:

[Cities Project](https://github.com/fredatgithub/Cities)

The next combobox is dependant on the previous combobox choice.
In other words a combobox choice loads the next combobox with correct values e.g. the selection of a continent will load the country combobox.

You have to put your code on the SelectedIndexChanged event e.g. ComboBoxSelectContinent_SelectedIndexChanged will load all the countries of the selected continent.